# If Java application has a memory leak, the JVM would eventually run out of memory and flag, right?

Tags: java, web-applications, memory, memory-leaks, jvm

I think the answer to this question should be yes...but I guess I'm not really sure, since I'm asking about it:)

I'm just trying to determine if my webapp has a memory leak somewhere. If the memory usage continues to increase, an Out of Memory error should be produced eventually, right?

Comment: Memory leaks do not necessarily grow over time (see my answer). If you do a bad thing 10 times and no more, you could still have a leak and less memory to utilize, but you'll never crash, yet your application would underperform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If you have a substantial leak you eventually get an OutOfMemoryError.

Although, if you have a small leak, it's possible to run for a long time without running out of memory. It depends on the size of the leak, heap size, and how long your servers run before an update or restart.

Comment: That is what I think I have, a small leak. Thank you for answering my question:)

Comment: If you have a small leak and need to prove it, sometimes a combination of load testing (increased request rate), and decreasing the heap size (less room for error) will make it happen faster. Once you prove it exists, it's that much easier to track down.

Comment: That's a really good idea. Can I do a load test on my webapp, but on my local pc? Is there an application available for such?

Comment: @katura - If you can run your webapp locally that would be recommended. It makes profiling and debugging easier. There are lots of load tests frameworks out there. One of the simplest for doing a "micro" or focused load tests is JMeter. But, it has limited functionality for a complex app. If you know which page or functionality to focus on, it could help you pinpoint it quickly. If you need to hit a large number of pages and maintain state in between, it could become unwieldy.

Comment: Yes, I can run my webapp locally. I think I have a general idea of where I could focus the test on. I'll look into this JMeter app as you've suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Yes if the memory usage continues to increase.

However, a memory leak is a situation where memory has been allocated and not released when it is no longer relevant. The definition **does not mean that it has to be recurring or growing**.

For instance, if you had 4GB of RAM in your JVM, had a bunch of leak events that ate up 3GB and are not going to have any more memory leak events, you are still restricted to the limited 1GB.

Therefore, you could very well have a leak, even a serious one, but not spot it until you've had enough events that would cause you to run out of memory or until the performance of other parts degenerates too much.

In my experience, these situations are more common that one would expect, making them notorious to track down.

Comment: I'm in that stage right now...the tracking down part. I have a vps with 432mb of memory and Tomcat/java has managed to consume as much as 254mb. I can't excuse the possibility of there being a memory leak. Why else would the memory seldom go down, and when it does, not by very much at all. Thank you Uri for your informative post.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually.  The JVM has a notion of maximum heap size, meaning if it reaches the limit and tries to allocate more and can't, it will try to garbage collect; if it still can't allocate memory, you will get an exception thrown.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find a memory leak, monitoring your webapp using jconsole might be a good idea. Also JProbe can be used to identify leaks.

Comment: Can those applications monitor a webapp on a local pc and on a remote host?

Comment: yes... both on local pc and remote host.. however, you need to configure you app server to allow jconsole read info from it... 
more info here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, looks like I have some reading to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools available for analyzing, and many times automatically isolating, possible memory leaks. [jhat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) ships with the JDK; [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) is free, and an example commercial offering is [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/home/index.jsp).